# Password management option without subscription monetization model?

Tags: windows, linux, osx, cross-platform, password-manager

1 Password used to be great. It's sad to see it moving towards a subscription model like LastPass and Dashlane have done. Further, 1PW has never supported Linux.

Is there an alternative commercially supported SOLID password management tool available that is just a one time purchase, following in the path that 1PW used to be?  Or is there any open source option that is also very well developed? (Worried about options like KeePass that seem well maintained, but you just never know.)

Requirements:

- I need it to work on macOS, Windows, Linux and in Safari, Chrome, Firefox browsers aside from a main console app like 1PW.
- I need to sync via Dropbox or another cloud service or via a direct sharing client-server architecture.

Comment: I use KeepassX since very long and am very happy, what are your worries about it ? Are there features missing ?

Comment: Actually I would never trust a company enough to use a closed source password manager.

Comment: @RoVo it might work well. I may need to look more closely at some macOS options from KeePass.

Comment: Enpaas, *baby*!